# Inserir imagem no banco de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Que tipo de variável eu uso para armazenar uma imagem no banco de dados?
E existe um comando especifico para isso? ou é só inserir como um registro qualquer?

Eu tenho uma tabela de produtos com os campos:

código,
nome,
preco,
imagem, na imagem eu pretendo armazenar uma foto do produto.

Comment: Use o tipo BLOB, não é uma variável, é o tipo do campo. Seria bom você dizer qual SGBD você usa, e se possível postar algum código e/ou deixar a sua dúvida mais específica.

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação você pretende usar brother?

Comment: Informe a linguagem de programação, o banco que você deseja gravar essa informação, porque, tudo são variáveis importantes para uma boa resposta!???????????

Comment: @HarryPotter verdade, e até mesmo por causa disso houve complicações nas respostas abaixo.

Comment: A verdade é essa as respostas levaram na cabeça por causa da pergunta que já devia era estar fechada antes de haver respostas.

Comment: A pergunta é boa mas ela devia ter sido melhor explicada, porque as respostas mudam de acordo se a aplicação é web ou desktop, acho que se ele alterar da para manter ela ativa ainda.

Comment: Sim, mas enquanto não é editada fica em suspenso.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha a pergunta é _quase_ boa, se o autor tivesse explicado o que pretende de forma clara seria boa a pergunta, mas do jeito que está é quase impossível responder. Me surpreendi com as tentativas de respostas sendo que não dava para entender o que o autor quis perguntar.

Comment: @Math surpreendente é ninguém ter fechado a pergunta logo.

Comment: @JorgeB. bom, eu costumo esperar um pouco para fechar, eu deixei meu comentário e esperava que o autor melhorasse, entretanto foram surgindo respostas, talvez o melhor teria sido fechar mesmo e se o op melhorasse reabria daí

Comment: @Math também acho, começo a concordar com o fechamento logo, senão dá asas a este tipo de perguntas até parecem interessantes e está arruinada.

Comment: Anderson, o Meta é a parte do site onde a gente dicute como funciona o SOPT. Sua pergunta foi citada [nos comentários a este post](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1420/201). Podes dar tua opinião lá? E se tiver alguma dúvida e quiser esclarecer algo não hesite em abrir uma pergunta lá no [meta].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

conforme ja mencionado, pode-se usar BLOB e LONGBLOB, mas **NÃO FAÇA ISSO**.

Existem diversas e diversas *tentações* em se realizar um armazenamento de imagens em bancos de dados, como:

***TENTAÇÕES***
 - facilidade de backup
 - acesso unico e uniforme entre múltiplos nós
 - listagem e contabilização de imagens por sql

porem, temos os verdadeiros calcanhares de aquiles:

***REALIDADE***
 - backup torna-se volumoso alem do normal
 - carga de memória do servidor de banco fica sobrecarregada com dados que não são relacionáveis em sí
 - volume de trafego de rede do servidor de banco aumenta substancialmente

Sugiro esquematizar uma forma inteligente de organização dos dados em uma estrutura de dados intuitiva, exemplo: /versao/ano/id-produto/fotos

Caso queira realizar uma centralização de dados e ponto único de acesso, tente filesystems distribuídos ou replicados, existem milhares de alternativas (GFS,GPFS,AFS,DFS mogileFS, extremfs)

E existem também as bases de documentos, onde hoje muitas se desvirtuaram e viraram NOSQL 
(S3,CouchDB, mongoDB, etc..)

Answer (score 3):

Fica difícil ajuda-lo sem saber qual SGBD e qual linguagem você está utilizando.
Entretanto, para exemplificar, vou utilizar o MySQL+PHP.

Respondendo a sua pergunta: no MySQL utiliza-se um campo do tipo LONGBLOB.

Agora, **eu acredito** não ser uma boa prática. Altere a sua aplicação e não faça isso.
Independente de estar no SGBD ou não, sua imagem vai estar em disco.
Isso só vai fazer seu banco de dados ficar mais "inchado"
Grave no SGBD apenas o caminho para a imagem, vai ficar mais leve.

Para fazer upload de imagens e gravar somente o caminho na base de dados. Pode ler a documentação do php sobre o assunto [aqui (link)](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Primeiro é preciso ter um formulário para seleccionar a imagem:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="salvar.php" method="post">
    Imagem: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Repare que o "action" do formulário aponta para "salvar.php". Veja como ficou:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/upload/imagens/'; //directório onde será gravado a imagem

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    //grava na base de dados, no campo imagem, somente o nome da imagem que ficou gravado na variável $uploadfile que criamos acima.
} else {
    //não foi possível concluir o upload da imagem.
}
?>
```

Comment: Por acaso ainda estes dias vi um [artigo](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64525/tr-2006-45.pdf) da microsoft sobre isso no SOEN, que segundo o estudo se a imagem for menor que 256K que a BD tem larga vantagem, se for maior que 1M o sistema de ficheiros tem larga vantagem. Embora seja a comparação SQLServer vs NTFS, acho que dá para ter uma ideia.

Comment: @JorgeB. é um excelente artigo para se traduzir e postar como pergunta/resposta (lógico, resumir o conteúdo). A fonte é confiável.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode guardar o caminho da imagem, onde ela está no seu ftp por exemplo:

```
foto_do_produto(varchar 100) - seu campo

/images/produtos/prod50156.png - o valor do campo
```

Para mais referências e exemplos de outras linguagens apesar de você não ter citado nenhuma na pergunta deixo está em php como exemplo [aqui](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Isso não insere de forma propriamente dita a imagem no banco de dados.

Comment: @Renan não mas eu apresentei uma solução prática, porque quando eu não sabia como fazer um upload eu também achava que a imagem ficava guardada no banco de dados e talvez o autor da pergunta não saiba disso ainda.