# Como salvar foto do perfil do facebook no banco de dados?

Tags: php, facebook, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

Eu tenho um botão que quando clica, conecta-se ao facebook e exibe os dados da pessoa num formulário para cadastro, nesse formulário a um campo do tipo text que me retorna o seguinte: `http://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?width=300`

Eu gostaria de salvar a foto que o link me retorna no banco de dados. Eu tava utilizando o `file_put_contents('...',file_get_contents())`, porém não está mais funcionando.

Comment: Não sei se estou correto, mas acredito que dava para salvar a imagem em uma pasta e no banco de dados salve o caminho dessa pasta ai carrega no formulário a imagem chamado o caminho gravado no banco de dados.

Comment: Anderson, obrigado pelo comentário! Imagine o seguinte: eu recebo a url: http://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?width=300 eu gostaria de saber como salvar esta imagem no banco de dados!

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse tópico quem sabe te ajuda
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16396/inserir-imagem-no-banco-de-dados

Comment: `file_put_contents`? Que erro que aparece? seria o `http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0`?

Comment: Isso ae Guilherme. Eu conseguir resolver meu problema, usando uma class.

Answer (score 1):

Usei esta class para resolver meu problema.

```
        class cUrl{
            public function file_get_contents_curl($url) 
            {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                return $data;
            }
        }
```

Comment: se essa é resposta correta, então marque como a resposta aceita.

Comment: @EduardoSeixas, olha minha, resposta, acredito que você vai ter um uso melhor do que usando a  função curl do php.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode acessar diretamente o json da imagem:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/4?fields=picture.width(750).height(750)
```

Exemplo:

```
function getImageFacebook($id) {
 $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'?fields=picture.width(300).height(300)';
          // faz a requisição a API passando a URL como parametro
          $json_string = file_get_contents($url);
          // usando a função json_decode e transformando em um array
          $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
          // retorna o número de likes
          echo '<pre>';
          print_r($json);
          echo '</pre>';

          $largura = $json['picture']['data']['width'];
          $altura = $json['picture']['data']['height'];
          $imagem = $json['picture']['data']['url'];
          echo '<img src="' . $imagem . '" width="' . $largura . '" height="' . $altura . '" border="0">';
        }
 getImageFacebook('67563683055');
```