# É viável o uso de BLOB para imagens em BD's?

Tags: banco-de-dados, imagem, blob

Estou projetando um banco de dados e cai na dúvida se eu deveria guardar imagens de profile em uma *field blob* na tabela ou guardar a imagem fisicamente em um *storage* e criar uma *field text* que contenha a URL da imagem para download.

Qual dos dois seria melhor e porquê? Até onde eu sei o *blob* precisa ser processado pela aplicação seria essa uma resposta para o não uso dele?

Comment: Assim sem pensar dizia-te para usares um *storage* mesmo, mas como são imagens de profile não sei se é assim tão obvio.

Comment: [É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/91) e
[Inserir imagem no banco de dados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16396/91)